# Would or Might in The Past

Tags: modal-verbs

> Perhaps I **would/might** have liked that movie the first time I watched it, but there is no way I'm going to watch it again.

I would like to know which modal verb between would and might is the right one I have to choose for the sentence above, in order to exactly get my point across.

Here is a little bit of context, of course:

A friend of mine asks me if we want to see again a movie he knows I saw many years ago.
He thinks that I enjoyed it that first time.
Unfortunately (it can sound strange), I just don't remember whether I really enjoyed it or not (maybe, or maybe not), but by no means I want to see it again.
Please, let me no if you need more details.

Answer (score 3):

"Might"  conveys the idea that there is a possibility that you liked the movie, even though you don't remember it now. 
"Would" would not be appropriate in the sentence in question.

" Probably I liked the movie when I first watched it, but I am by no means going to watch it again" may be an alternative more linear sentence to yours.

Comment: Thank you Josh. Your sentence is definitely more linear than mine. However, I needed to know which was more appropriate and grammatical between would and might. It is for my English comprehension.

Comment: http://www.englishpage.com/modals/might.html

Comment: The above link might be of help to your understanding of how to use "might".

Answer (score 2):

While Josh61's answer is correct, you could also simplify it by just saying:

> Perhaps I liked that movie the first time I watched it, but there is no way I'm going to watch it again.

*Perhaps* indicates it was a possibility same as *might*, so it sounds a bit redundant to me.

Comment: Ok, I see. Anyway, can we say that, without the word perhaps, the sentence (with might) is "acceptable"? Thank you

Comment: Yes, that is OK too.